# How to initialize object variable in another object constructor (more details)?

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor

I'm still a beginner so cut me some slack.

I have 5 class but only 2 are needed for my question. This is a question in my assignment so no need to be too particular. I have been tasked to make a java terminal system to store and display lecturer (part time and full time), lecturers address, and classes information.

My code will check if there is a part time lecturer to display (this includes the address object since it is part of the lecturer information) . If not, it will prompt the user to enter the part time lecturer details. When entering the part time details I am not sure on how to enter the address without recreating the object.
here is my codes

This is part time class

```
public class PartTime extends Lecturer{
    private double hourlyRate;
    private int hoursWorked;
    //classR = class resposible
    private ClassInfo classR;
    
    PartTime(){
        classR = new ClassInfo();
    }
    PartTime(String staffNo, String name, int contactNo, int noClasses, Address add, double hourlyRate, int hoursWorked, ClassInfo classR){
        super(staffNo, name, contactNo, noClasses, add);
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
        this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
        this.classR = classR;
    }

    public double getHourlyRate(){
        return this.hourlyRate;
    }
    public int getHoursWorked(){
        return this.hoursWorked;
    }
    public void setHourlyRate(double newHourlyRate){
        this.hourlyRate = newHourlyRate;
    }
    public void setHoursWorked(int newHoursWorked){
        this.hoursWorked = newHoursWorked;
    }
    
    public void displayClassR(){
        System.out.println("Class No           : "+ classR.getClassNo());
        System.out.println("Subject Name       : "+ classR.getSubjectName());
        System.out.println("Number Of Students : "+ classR.getNoStudents());
        System.out.println("Start Date         : "+ classR.getStartDate());
        System.out.println("End Date           : "+ classR.getEndDate());
    }
}
```

This is lecturer class

```
public class Lecturer{

    private String staffNo, name;
    private int contactNo, noClasses;
    private final Address add;

    Lecturer(){
        add = new Address();
    }
    Lecturer(String staffNo, String name, int contactNo, int noClasses, Address add){
        this.staffNo = staffNo;
        this.name = name;
        this.contactNo = contactNo;
        this.noClasses = noClasses;
        this.add = add;
    }

    public String getStaffNo(){
        return this.staffNo;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getContactNo(){
        return this.contactNo;
    }
    public int getNoClasses(){
        return this.noClasses;
    }
    public void displayAdd(){
        System.out.println("Unit Number : "+ add.getUnitNo());
        System.out.println("Street Name : "+ add.getStreetName());
        System.out.println("City        : "+ add.getCity());
        System.out.println("Postcode    : "+ add.getPostcode());
    }
    public void setStaffNo(String newStaffNo){
        this.staffNo = newStaffNo;
    }
    public void setName(String newName){
        this.name = newName;
    }
    public void setContactNo(int newContactNo){
        this.contactNo = newContactNo;
    }
    public void setNoClasses(int newNoClasses){
        this.noClasses = newNoClasses;
    }
    public void setAdd(String newUnitNo, String newStreetName, String newCity, int newPostcode){
        add.setUnitNo(newUnitNo);
        add.setStreetName(newStreetName);
        add.setCity(newCity);
        add.setPostcode(newPostcode);
    }

}
```

You can ignore the menu part

```
import java.io.*;
class Main{
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Address add = new Address();
    static ClassInfo classI = new ClassInfo();
    static FullTime ft = new FullTime();
    static PartTime pt = new PartTime();

    static String staffNo, name, classNo, subjectName, startDate, endDate, unitNo, streetName, city;
    static int contactNo, noClasses, hoursWorked, noStudents, postcode, select;
    static double annualSalary, hourlyRate;
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //menu looping
        do{
            System.out.println("=======================");
            System.out.println("|      Main Menu      |");
            System.out.println("|   Select an option  |");
            System.out.println("|    1. Lecturer      |");
            System.out.println("|    2. Class Info    |");
            System.out.println("|    3. File Actions  |");
            System.out.println("|    0. Exit          |");
            System.out.println("=======================");
         
            select = scan.nextInt();
            switch(select){
                case 1:
                    lecturerMenu();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    classInfoMenu();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fileMenu();
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Exiting...");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Error please select again");
            }
        }while(select !=0);
        
}
```

Eventually it will make its way to the part where the user adds part time lecturer data. the set is incomplete as i didnt know how to do the addresspart

```
public static void newPartTime(){
        
        System.out.println("Enter Part Time Lecturer Details");
        System.out.print("Enter Staff Number: ");
        scan.nextLine();
        staffNo = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Contact Number: ");
        contactNo = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter Hourly Rate: ");
        hourlyRate = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Hours Worked: ");
        hoursWorked = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Address");
        System.out.print("Enter Unit Number: ");
        scan.nextLine();
        unitNo = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Street Name: ");
        streetName = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter City: ");
        city = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Postcode: ");
        postcode = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        if(classI == null){
            System.out.println("There is no class available. Please add a new class");
            newClassInfo();
        }else{
            pt.setStaffNo(staffNo);
            pt.setName(name);
            pt.setContactNo(contactNo);
            pt.setNoClasses(noClasses);
            pt.set

        }
        }

    }
```

Normally I would do this for my declaration:

```
static FullTime ft = new FullTime(var1, var1 ,var3, address);
```

Am I able to recreate the object or should I just add a method for set address in part time?

Comment: following your code you should create your Address object and pass it on constructor because your variable of reference Address in Lecture class is final.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Object of the address class and set values to that and then set the object into your part time object.

Comment: does this mean that I create the object (address) with filler values? if so i want to still have a checker (if null) to make sure that it shows "no address. please enter address" when someone tries to display when there is still no user inputted data

Comment: set null if user does not enter data related to address.